# Accessing an arraylist which created in method from another class

Tags: java

I have three classes named ReadArticle ,Article and Command.
I want to use arrArticle which defined in ReadArticle and created in ReadArticle's readArticleCommandFile method in Article class.
In command class ı first call readArticleCommandFile method in ReadArticle class and makeArticleObject method in Article class like this

```
//I created their articleReader object from ReadArticle class
// and created article object from Article class
articleReader.readArticleCommandFile(articleName);
article.makeArticleObject();
```

Here is ReadArticle class. I created arrArticle in here.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadArticle {
    public static ArrayList<String> arrArticle = new ArrayList<>();

public void readArticleCommandFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String line;
    System.out.println("in read article command file");
    try (BufferedReader article = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        System.out.println("in try");
        while ((line = article.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.endsWith(" ")) {
                arrArticle.add(line);
            } else {
                while (line.endsWith(" ")) {
                    line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                }
                arrArticle.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrArticle() {
    return arrArticle;
}

public static void setArrArticle(ArrayList<String> arrArticle) {
    ReadArticle.arrArticle = arrArticle;
   }
 }
```

In Article class ı want to use arrArticle arraylist from ReadArticle class. I created ReadArticle Object and get arrArticle with getArrArticle method. Then ı want to use arrArticle in makeArticleObject()

```
 ReadArticle readArticle = new ReadArticle();
 public  ArrayList<String> myArticleArray = readArticle.getArrArticle();
 int lengthArticleArray = myArticleArray.size();
 public void makeArticleObject() {
    System.out.println("now");
    System.out.println(lengthAuthorArticleArray);
    System.out.println(lengthArticleArray);

    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String sentence : myArticleArray) {
        array1.add(sentence.substring(9));
    }}
```

It prints now and then 0 for length of myArticleArray. This shows there is some problem while getting arrArticle from ReadArticle class. How can ı use arrArticle arraylist without any problem in Article class?

Comment: You are not demonstrating a problem. Your code starts with an empty `ArrayList`. So if the importing code finds no file, or finds an empty file, you will indeed end up with an empty `ArrayList` object where no elements were added.

Answer (score 0):

Does it even write into the array at some point? Maybe it can’t find any data to put into the array

Comment: I passed data in ReadArticle class readArticleCommandFile(file name)